# AngularJS Jasmine Test - how to skip over a request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, httpbackend

We have a set of test cases which is common for many different forms. 
Some of the forms may trigger a lazy loader which would prefetch some data in their post section of the directive, so firing a HTTP GET.

In the common test's beforeEach, I thus have to handle it, else I get 
Unexpected request: GET /bla/requests/generateJson/something No more request expected

I added $httpBackend.when("GET",//generateJson/(.+)/).respond(); before scope.$digest(); in the test's beforeEach. Now, the error changes to

Error: Unflushed requests: 1

Adding 
$httpBackend.flush();

causes the test cases when the GET call is fired to pass, but all test cases which do not fire a GET, fail with error

Error: No pending request to flush !

How can I handle that? I just want this test to ignore the GET completely, whether it is present or not. Can I somehow determine if the GET was fired, and so react with flush?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that no calls were made to the `$httpBackend` mock with the `verifyNoOutstandingRequest()` method. You can also verify that any expected calls to the backend were successful with the `verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()` method. So you code would look something like this:

```
describe('Test HTTP Service', function () {

    var $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $httpBackend.when('GET', '//generateJson/(.+)/').respond();
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('calls the backend', function () {
        $httpBackend.GET('//generateJson/Petr/');
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });

    it('does not call the backend', function () {
        // Some action that does call $httpBackend
    });

});
```

More information can be found on the `$httpBackend` [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) page. Also, check out [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2431) discussion over on GitHUb.